# How to resolve time-out Dynamics 365 database synchronization Failed?

Tags: iis, synchronization, timeout, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

After compile my modules (has been executed), 
I run Dynamics 365 database synchronization.

I get this error below:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       System.Net.WebException: **The operation has timed out**
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Tools.ProjectSystem.DevFabricAccessor.StartWorkerProcess()
>      at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Tools.ProjectSystem.DevFabricDebuggingHost.WarmupAppPool(Int32 RetryCount)
>      at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Tools.ProjectSystem.Debugger.IISExpressHostSupplier.InitializeDebuggingHostSupplier()
>      at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Tools.ProjectSystem.Debugger.IISExpressHostSupplier.RestartRuntime()
>      at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Tools.BuildTasks.SyncEngineWrapper.Sync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Info: My DEV environment is on *Cloud*.

I tried to restard my *IIS* and run again the Synch, but nothing change.

Do you have any idea about this issue? There is any way to resolve it?Are there any tips and trick?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried sync'ing via command line and increasing the timeout?

See the below links for examples of how to do this. The switch is `SqlTimeOut`. It may be undocumented...not sure I just decompiled the assembly to see the options.

- https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/b/axilitynet/posts/ax7-database-synchronization-w-o-visual-studio
- https://d365technext.blogspot.com/2018/06/database-synchronization-using-power.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kwitny I will check about these objects.